# Stop screen capture including popup on UWP app of Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I stopped screen capturing on my UWP app by ([Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/167ac921-4898-41e8-99d3-54e81060973c/isscreencaptureenabled12395123881235612390?forum=winstoreapp))

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            var mDispatcher = rootFrame.Dispatcher;
            await mDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
                view.IsScreenCaptureEnabled = isSettingEnabled;
            });
```

However, when the screenshot is made during the app display a popup, it looks like this.
[image]
My question is how do I remove the popup content and make the screenshot fully black.

Comment: Could you share a mini sample could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Hi, After applying the above code snippet on app.xaml.cs and take a screenshot when your app displays a popup. Then paste it on Paint. The app will be all blacked-out but popup displays.

Comment: Ok, I will make sample test it, please wait.

Comment: When set `IsScreenCaptureEnabled` as false, then take screenshot , the app windows will black but not popup the notice in my side.

Comment: Please tell your app's target version and OS version.

Comment: Hi, App is on Windows 10 (10240) (Min and Target versions both). My OS is Window 10 1909 (18363.657)

Comment: Hope you understood my question. When your app is displaying a popup message take a screenshot. The app will be blacked-out but a popup is not. Just like the screenshot I posted.

Comment: OMG, I consider it throw the popup when take screenshot. Ok I got.

Comment: I make a messagedialog for simulating the scenario, I could reproduce this, but It's by design, because the messagedialog rendered out of current application-view, so it will not response IsScreenCaptureEnabled property, and currently we have no such api to detect snipping tool running from uwp app. so the better way is close the dialog before take screenshot manually or make Popup control to replace above MessageDialog.

Comment: I consider this a bug in UWP. You can post "by design" as the answer and I will mark it as the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stop screen capture including popup on UWP app of Windows 10

I make a messagedialog for simulating the scenario, it is reproduced, but It's by design, because the `MessageDialog` rendered out of current `ApplicationView`, so it will not response `IsScreenCaptureEnabled` property, and currently we have no such api to detect snipping tool running from uwp app. so the better way is close the dialog before take screenshot manually or make [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) control or [`ContentDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog) to replace above [`MessageDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog).